# SAPUI5: Getting argument as undefined, passed while routing from one view to another

Tags: data-binding, routes, navigation, sapui5

I am passing arguments from `Master` to `Detail` view while routing, but getting it as undefined.

Code from *MasterController.js*

```js
onPressItemDetail: function(evt) {
    var object = evt.getSource().
    getBindingContext().
    getModel().
    getProperty(evt.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath());

    var context = {
        object: object,
        bindingContext: evt.getSource().getBindingContext()
    };
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.navTo("fourth", context);
}
```

Code from *DetailController.js*

```js
onInit: function() {
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.attachRouteMatched(function(oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getParameter("name") !== "fourth") {
            return;
        }
        var object = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").object;
        var bindingContext = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").bindingContext;

    }, this);
}
```

Routing configuration from `Component.js`

```js
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "umicoreMP.view",
        "controlId": "app",
        "controlAggregation": "pages"
    },
    "routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "first",
        "target": "first"
    }, {
        "pattern": "secondview",
        "name": "second",
        "target": "second"
    }, {
        "pattern": "thirdview",
        "name": "third",
        "target": "third"

    }, {
        "pattern": "changeitem",
        "name": "fourth",
        "target": "fourth"
    }],
    "targets": {
        "first": {
            "viewName": "FirstView"
        },
        "second": {
            "viewName": "SecondView"
        },
        "third": {
            "viewName": "ThirdView"
        },
        "fourth": {
            "viewName": "ChangeItem"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route pattern must contain the desired parameter in the following format:

```js
{
  "pattern": "changeitem/{object}",
  "name": "fourth",
  "target": "fourth"
}
```

`oRouter.navTo()` contains the desired route and an object which contains the parameters of the route:

```js
oRouter.navTo("fourth", {object: property});
```

Passing the bindingcontext as a parameter is not recommended (and in this case, not possible) because it's an object and it's not safe to pass object like this in URL.

If you want to access the data which belongs to the property passed to the Detail view, you can fetch it from the model.

Assuming that your model is assigned to the component, each view has access to that. Here you can bind the proper entry of the model to the view in several ways, for example:

```js
oRouter.attachRouteMatched(function (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.getParameter("name") !== "fourth") {
    return;
  }
  var object = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").object;
  this.getView().bindElement({path: object, model: "nameOfTheModel"});
}
```

The exact value of the path depends on the model (JSONModel or ODataModel). Model name should be defined in `component.js`.

With this `bindElement` function call you can assign the specific row of the model to the view, so controls in the view can access properties of the selected data entry with relative binding:

```xml
<Text text="{propertyInModel}" />
```